# SAP B1 SDK - global update of BOM

Tags: c#, sdk, sapb1, materials

I need to globally update BOMs. Tool in SAP B1 is allowing us to add items to BOM but only by ItemCode. We do not have ItemCodes in sort order to add items to it. By oRecordset and custom SQL query I can find BOMs where I need to add this new materials, but SAP B1 now supporting stages in BOM what mean i need to add this item to specific stage, also with specific stage is also asociated VisOrder of item. How I can add componenet to specific stage, some VisOrder where all other components behind this one need be also updated. ChildNumis easy because will be max ChildNum in BOM +1.

Here is example:
Before:

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

How I can do this in runtime by C#? Can you share some code how I can do this?
Thx